# Отфильтровать ArrayList исключив строки с заглавными буквами

Tags: java, arraylist, фильтрация

Есть список `stringList`, элементами которого являются строки.

Нужно написать метод `correctedList()`, который создаст и вернет новый список,  одержащий все строки, не содержащие буквы только в верхнем регистре(Заглавные).

```java
public static List<String> correctedList(List<String> stringList) {
    return stringList;
}
```

пробовал прогонять через циклы `for`, а также с помощью метода `Arrays.sort(T[],Comparator)`, ни одно, ни другое не получилось.

Пытался гуглить, не получилось. Прошу помощи или хотя бы подсказки

```java
public static List<String> correctedList(List<String> stringList) {
    String [] string = new String[stringList.size()];
    for (int j = 0; j < string.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < stringList.toArray().length; i++) {
            if (stringList.indexOf(i) <= 'Z' && stringList.indexOf(i) >= 'A') {
                stringList.remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
    return stringList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача не совсем о *сортировке*, т.е. об упорядочении списка, а скорее о фильтрации данных.

Условие *не содержащие буквы **только** в верхнем регистре(Заглавные)* можно проверить при помощи регулярного выражения `\\p{Lu}+` (для обработки *любых* заглавных букв, а не только английского алфавита) и метода `String::matches`.

Также для преобразования списка удобно использовать Stream API:

```java
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public static List<String> correctedList(List<String> stringList) {
   return stringList.stream()
       .filter(str -> !str.matches("\\p{Lu}+"))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Реализация с циклом может выглядеть так:

```java
public static List<String> correctedList(List<String> stringList) {
   List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
   for (String str : stringList) {
       if (!str.matches("\\p{Lu}+")) {
           result.add(str);
       }
   }
   return result;
}
```

---

Альтернативное решение -- проверять содержимое каждой строки при помощи `Character::isUpperCase` и `Stream::allMatch`:

```java
public static List<String> correctedListNotAllCaps(List<String> stringList) {
   return stringList.stream()
       .filter(str -> !str.chars().allMatch(Character::isUpperCase))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Также можно отфильтровать и удалить строки, содержащие хотя бы одну заглавную букву:

```java
public static List<String> correctedListNoneCaps(List<String> stringList) {
   return stringList.stream()
       .filter(str -> str.chars().noneMatch(Character::isUpperCase))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

Тест:

```java
List<String> data = Arrays.asList("A", "a", "Aa", "AAA", "aaa", "aaA");

System.out.println("regex  : " + correctedList(data));
System.out.println("not all: " + correctedListNotAllCaps(data));
System.out.println("no caps: " + correctedListNoneCaps(data));
```

```
regex  : [a, Aa, aaa, aaA]
not all: [a, Aa, aaa, aaA]
no caps: [a, aaa]
```

Comment: На счет первого решения с помощью регулярного выражения не работало т.к правильно выглядела вот так: ".*[A-Z].*". Проблема решена спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @НикитаШафтисов, `.*[A-Z].*` - проверяет наличие _хотя бы одной заглавной буквы_, а мой первоначальный вариант (как записано в условии) -- что строка состоит **только из заглавных букв**.